# how to allocate an 128 bit array with new Intel instructions with dynamic memory?

Tags: c, instruction-set

I am new working with new Intel instructions, so until now I just had been working with static memory, so I have a declaration as:

```
__m128i  pResult[10];
```

But now I am wondering if it is possible to allocate the memory in a dynamic way, as using `malloc` or `calloc` but for this new instructions.

Comment: You can't use malloc, it doesn't have a sufficient alignment guarantee. Check your CRT for a version that allows specifying alignment. For GCC it's memalign() or posix_memalign(), for MSVC it's _aligned_malloc()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other malloc:

```
__m128i *p = (__m128i*)malloc(10 * sizeof(__m128i));
```

Comment: You should use `calloc()` rather than `malloc()` to make the intent more clear. Also `calloc()` zeroes while `malloc()` does not.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: you should use `calloc` if and only if you want memory zeroed, IMO.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan calloc makes the intent less clear than malloc unless the intent is to clear the memory, but no such intent was stated.

Comment: @JimBalter: `calloc()` makes clear the intent is to allocate memory for an array of `M` items of size `N`. `malloc()` does no such thing. And since it is never valid to use uninitialized memory in a C program...

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan malloc is for allocating memory, calloc is for allocating it and clearing it. M*N is just as clear as two arguments of M and N. There is no evidence that the uninitialized memory will be used before being set. I would never hire anyone who routinely uses calloc where malloc is adequate, or who assumes that all allocated memory must be cleared. Goodbye.

Comment: Casting the return value of `malloc()` is a bad idea too.

Comment: @mip: what would you do instead?

Comment: @KeithRandall: I'm guessing not cast it.

Comment: @JimBalter: The question gives a declaration and mentions a static context; that's probably why memory initialization may be assumed as intended.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: not casting it gives me a `invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’` error.

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.  You don't need the cast in C.  I'm back and forth between C and C++ so often I'm in the habit of always including it.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis The thing is called `pResult`; it's grossly irrational to assume that it needs to be cleared.